# Starting multiple discord tokens discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, token

How would I be able to start multiple token with discord.py (discord python) with fetching the tokens from and external and then run each one.
How would I be to give them a random status?

Comment: if i understand this correctly, you have multiple discord bot accounts, and want to run them all using one script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create multiple bot files and put another token in each file